# tomcat 7 jndi + spring

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat7

I am developing sample web application using:

- Tomcat 7
- Spring 2.5
- Mysql 5.6
- Eclipse Kepler
- Java 6

Am trying to make use of tomcat connection pooling.

When I start the server I get exception as below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'springDataSource' of bean class [com.mygroup.mc.dao.PreFillDAO]: Bean property 'springDataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:801)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:651)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    ... 48 more
```

In context.xml (within META-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/mcDB" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="root" password="password"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TESTDB"
        maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" />

</Context>
```

In dao.xml:

```
<bean id="springDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/mcDB</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
      <bean id= "preFillDAO"  class="com.mygroup.mc.dao.PreFillDAO" scope="prototype">
       <property name="springDataSource" ref="springDataSource" />
   </bean>
```

In web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mcDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

Below is the PreFillDAO class:

```
package com.mygroup.mc.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.JdbcDaoSupport;



public class PreFillDAO extends JdbcDaoSupport{

    public List fetchUserRoles() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList("select distinct column1 from syn_table_1 ");
    }

}
```

Is there anything am missing? Should I make an entry in conf/server.xml as well?

Comment: post your PreFillDAO class also

Comment: I guess your PreFillDAO class expects property springDataSource to be a DataSource not a factory bean.

Comment: I have changed the bean reference "dataSource" instead of "springDataSource" and the application deployed successfully without any exception. I couldn't answer to my own question and hence sending this comment to let others know that the problem has been fixed. Thanks for your time guys.